# Dynamic column based highcharts feeding data with jquery and php

Tags: php, jquery, highcharts

I am trying to build column based highcharts, and here is my code in jquery:

```
var options = {
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'column'
            },
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
            title: {
                text: 'PCP Histogram',
                x: -20
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: [{}]
            },
            legend: {
                        layout: 'vertical',
                        align: 'right',
                        verticalAlign: 'top',
                        x: -10,
                        y: 100,
                        borderWidth: 0
                    },
            tooltip: {
                        formatter: function() {
                        var s = '<b>'+ this.x +'</b>';

                            $.each(this.points, function(i, point) {
                            s += '<br/>'+point.series.name+': '+point.y;
                            });

                            return s;
                        },  
                        shared: true
                },
            series: [{},{}]
        };
                   $.ajax({
            url: "file.php",

            type: "post",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data){

                options.xAxis.categories = data.categories;
                options.series[0].name = 'Avg1';
                options.series[0].data = data.avg1;
                options.series[1].name = 'Avg2';
                options.series[1].data = data.avg2;

                var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
```

And I getting the data from file php like this: 
file.php

```
    $graph_data = array('categories'=>$categories, 'avg1'=>$avg, 'avg2'=>$avg);

print json_encode($graph_data, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

It is working fine with two columns per category, 
What I want now is: the graph_data can have n number of avg datas, 
so basically it will be n number of columns.

```
   $graph_data = array('categories'=>$categories, 'avg1'=>$avg1, ... 'avgn'=>$avgn);
```

When I do it manually it works, but I will not know how many of them will be there, so I want the code to do i.

Any idea how I can do it? 
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

make an array of avg instead of having avg1, avg2 etc....

```
$graph_data = array('categories'=>$categories, 'avgs'=>$array_of_avgs)
```

then in javascript side

```
success: function(data){

            options.xAxis.categories = data.categories;
            for(var i in data.avgs){
               options.series[i].name = 'Avg'+i;
               options.series[i].data = data.avgs[i];
            }


            var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
```

And everything will be fine

Comment: Hi, how should I define the series above, when I try your code, it gives an error, Can not set a property 'name' to non-object. I think the series in chart options is the problem. Do you know how cab I fix it?